# migrate only recent posts

Tags: posts

Is there an easy way to move only the last five or so posts over to a dev site? It is a clone of the live site but people have been updating the live site after we cloned it.

Answer (score 0):

The built in WordPress export page (Tools > Export) has a date range selector. Can you move over the last month's posts and delete the extras?